# Javascript RegExp type casting

Tags: javascript, regex, casting

I have defined a few simple regular expression as:

```
var PIPE= /^\|/;
var START= /^{{/;

var s= "{{hello";

var tSet={PIPE:true, START:true}
var test= "";

for(t in tSet){
    if(s.match(t)!=null){
        test= test+ s.match(t);
    }
}
```

but it never matches anything, so I looked for the type of t

```
typeof t;  //returns string
```

but t is a string. How do I make sure that t is the variable that contains the regular expression? I tried

```
for(t in tSet){
    var b= new RegExp(t);
    if(s.match(b)!=null){
        test= test+ s.match(b);
    }
}
```

but it still doesn't work. How can I typecast it so that it recognizes t as a regular expression and not a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your code. First is your initialisation of the `tSet` object. You're creating an object with string->boolean pairs. A JSON representation would be:

```
{
    "PIPE":true,
    "START":true
}
```

Next, when you iterate over the object with `for (x in y)`, `x` is each key in the object, not the value.

You can use `tSet[t]` to get the boolean value.

To get the regex values from the names of the variables, the window object allows this: `window[t]`.

Following, this you end up with:

```
var PIPE= /^\|/;
var START= /^{{/;

var s= "{{hello";

var tSet={PIPE:true, START:true}
var test= "";

for(t in tSet){
    if (!tSet[t]) { // If the value is false
        continue; // Skip this one and continue to the next
    }
    if(s.match(window[t])!=null){
        test = test + s.match(window[t]);
    }
}
```

At this point however, there is a much easier way and I think it may be what you were trying to do in the first place. Supposing you don't need the boolean, you should use an array:

```
var PIPE = /^\|/;
var START = /^{{/;

var s = "{{hello";

var tSet = [PIPE, START] // This creates an array with the values of the variables.
var test = "";

for (var i = 0; i < tSet.length; i++) { // For each regex in the array
    if(s.match(tSet[i]) != null){
        test = test + s.match(tSet[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't how JS works. If you create an object as so: `var foo = {bar: "baz"}`, you get a string to string mapping of "bar" to "baz". The key is not interpreted as a variable but rather as a string as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). You can try it yourself. Execute `var PIPE=/^\|/; var START=/^{{/; var tSet={PIPE:true, START:true}; console.log(tSet); for (t in tSet) { console.log(typeof t); console.log(t);}`. You get `string PIPE string START`

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of `{[PIPE]:true, [START]:true}`, fixed.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are in a **browser-environment**, you can access a variable by it's name using the `window` object:

```js
var a = 'test'
var b = 'a'
console.log(window[b]); // test
```

In your case:

```js
var PIPE= /^\|/;
var START= /^{{/;

var s= "{{hello";

var tSet={PIPE:true, START:true}
var test= "";

for(t in tSet){
  if(s.match(window[t])!=null){
    test= test+ s.match(window[t]);
    console.log(test)
  }
}
```

Comment: To clarify: in a browser environment, you can access a *global* variable by its name using `window`. Since you should avoid creating globals, this isn’t too useful in most cases.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, yes, thats correct. I'll update the answer to have this as well.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, answer updated. Will appreciate if you cast your down-vote (in case the down-vote is yours here). Thanks!

Comment: Well, you missed the point about the globals. As soon as you put this in any sort of scope (e.g., an IIFE), your code will fail to work.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the window[b] function analyses the environment in which b is defined in?

Comment: @sapphirecloud, In case you define a global, you can use `window['GLOBAL_VARIABLE_NAME']` to access the variable. (notice the string here). If `b='GLOBAL_VARIABLE_NAME'`, then `window[b] == window['GLOBAL_VARIABLE_NAME']`. The `b` variable can have different values in different places in your code.

Comment: @sapphirecloud `window` is not a function, it’s an object which is effectively the implicit top-level scope in a browser environment. If you create a global, or a variable in top-level scope, it is added to window. E.g. `a = 1; (function() { var a = 2; return window['a'] })()` gives `1`, not `2`.

Comment: Do not promote the practice of using strings to get properties from the `window` object.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that when you write:

```
var PIPE= /^\|/;
```

the right hand side is a RegExp literal, so *PIPE* is a reference to a RegExp instance. Then when you do:

```
var tSet={PIPE:true, START:true}
```

*PIPE* is treated as a string literal, not a variable, so you effectively get:

```
var tSet={"PIPE":true, "START":true}
```

if you want the variable name to be treated as a variable, you can use:

```
var tSet = {[PIPE]:true, [START]:true}
```

but since a RegExp object can't be used as a plain Object property name (you might use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for that), it's serialised back to a string, the property name becomes literally:

```
"/^\|/"
```

and

```
s.match(t)
```

becomes:

```
s.match("/^\|/")
```

So, using a Map, which allows you to use an object (or any type) as a property "name":

```js
var PIPE= /^\|/;
var START= /^{{/;

var s= "{{hello";

var tSet= new Map();
tSet.set(PIPE, true);
tSet.set(START, true);
var test= "";

for(var [key, value] of tSet){
    if (s.match(key) != null) {
        test = test + s.match(key)[0];
    }
}

console.log(test); // {{
```

However, I'm not sure support for Map is sufficient for it to be used on the general web, though you might get away with it in a restricted environment of only the latest browsers.

The *value* part isn't used in the above, I guess you'll use that to determine whether to do the test or not, so:

```
if (tSet.get(key) && s.match(key) != null) {
```

will only use the key if the related value is truthy.

Comment: I'd be interested to know the reason for the downvote. This seems to be answer OP's question and in quite a bit of detail without being _too_ long.